# I need to replicate this from Java to JavaScript (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, signature, cryptojs

I try to get the same functionality of java class to replicate in NodeJs, but I can't do it. I don't understand all the JavaCode, specialy when the instance sing() (what's return). for that can't replicate into NodeJs

Java Code

```
public String generateSignature(String key, String stringToSign) throws Exception {
    Signature signatureInstance = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithRSA");

    ServiceKeyRep keyRep = new ServiceKeyRep(KeyRep.Type.PRIVATE, "RSA", "PKCS#8",      Base64.getDecoder().decode(key));

    PrivateKey resolvedPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keyRep.readResolve();

    signatureInstance.initSign(resolvedPrivateKey);           
    
    byte[] bytesToSign = stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8");

    
    signatureInstance.update(bytesToSign);
    
    String signatureString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes);

    return signatureString;
}
```

And I try this on Node JS

```
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('myKey.pem', 'utf-8');
const stringToSign = new Int8Array([ myData ]);
const data = Buffer.from(stringToSign);  
const sign = crypto.sign("RSA-SHA256", data , privateKey);  
const signature = sign.toString('base64');  

//Printing the signature 
console.log(`Signature:\n\n ${signature}`);
```

but when I print, the out is not the same

Answer (score 1):

Using `crypto` library we can do something similar in JS. Adapt as appropriate, this is just a reference.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

function generateSignature(key, stringToSign) {
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(key, 'utf-8');

  const sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
  sign.update(stringToSign);

  const signature = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');

  return signature;
}

const key = 'myKey.pem';
const stringToSign = 'myData';

const signature = generateSignature(key, stringToSign);

console.log(`Signature:\n\n${signature}`);
```

Comment: thx i fix with your post, I forget some, and when see your post I fix and now work it!